# No output after running the program

Tags: c++

To keep it short, I'm quite a beginner at c++ and I'm learning character sequences.

Here's my problem: I'm trying to change every word with an even number of letters to a symbol ( # ), but I think that I'm approaching the problem in a bad way. I get nothing when running it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[101];
    cin.getline(s,101);
    int i;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if(strchr(s,' ')) // searching for a space
        {}
        else
            if((strlen(s)%2==0)) //trying to find if the word has an even number
            {
                strcat(s,"#");         // I'm sticking the # character to the word and then deleting everything after #.
                strcpy(s+i,s+i+1);
                cout<<s;
            }
            else
                cout<<"Doens't exist";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the compilation or running ?

Comment: My bad. Fixed the title. The problem occurs when running the program.

Comment: What is program input ?

Comment: A sentence. The program should change every word with an even number of letter to the symbol #

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` to avoid buffer overflows / overruns.  You can access `std::string` like an array too.  It has `find` and `replace` methods.

Comment: Note that you're using at most not `C++` but `C`, as library `<string.h>` comes from `C`. In `C++` there is `<string>` that gives more easy methods to work with strings.

Comment: @Pavel:  The C language doesn't have `cin` nor `getline`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, yes, because of this I wrote *at most*

Comment: Why do you `cout<<s;` inside `for` if you want to do replacing and then print `s` one time? Start from moving the line to a position before `return 0`.

Answer (score 1):

the only flow of code which doesnot contain cout is

```
if(strchr(s,' ')) // searching for a space
    {}
```

so debug this.

Comment: for beginners it is recommended to put multiple print statements in different flow  to understand what is really happening vs what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution (algorithm) is completely wrong! First you should separate each word by space,

```
if(strchr(s,' '))
```

then you should find length of separated word and then replace it to #.

Answer (score 0):

Look what will happen if you input a single word with an even number of letters with space at end like `abcd` . Your program will search for space five times and every time do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // declare input string and read it
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);

    // declare vector of strings to store words,
    // and string tmp to temporarily save word

    vector <string> vec;
    string tmp = "";

    // iterate through each character of input string

    for(auto c : s)
    {
        // if there is space push the word to vector,
        // clear tmp string
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            vec.push_back(tmp);
            tmp = "";
            continue;
        }

        // add character to temporary string
        tmp += c;
    }

    // push last word to vector
    vec.push_back(tmp);

    // clear the input string
    s = "";

    // iterate through each word
    for(auto w : vec)
    {
        // if number of word's characters are odd
        // just add the word itself
        // otherwise add '#' symbol
            (w.size() % 2) ? s += w : s += '#';
    s += ' ';
    }

    // remove last space
    s.erase(s.begin() + s.size() - 1, s.begin() + s.size());


    cout << s;
}
```